# why is this two functions not giving me the same answer?

Tags: python, list, function, append

Write a function named append_sum that has one parameter — a list named named lst.
The function should add the last two elements of lst together and append the result to lst. It should do this process three times and then return lst.
For example, if lst started as [1, 1, 2], the final result should be [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8].

*solutions-1*

```
def append_sum(lst):
   lst.append(lst[2] + lst[1])
   lst.append(lst[2] + lst[1])
   lst.append(lst[2] + lst[1])
   return lst
```

```
print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

ans = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]

*solution-2*

```
def append_sum(lst):
  lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
  lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
  lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
  return lst
```

```
print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

ans = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider: `lst[2]` is an *absolute* index, while `lst[-1]` is a *relative* index, based on the length of the list. If the list grows beyond 3 elements (where `lst[2]` would work) then `lst[2]` is still going to give the same answer, no matter how big the list gets. However, the same cannot be true if you count indices from the end of a list that can expand.

This is easily shown with:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

for x in range(4, 10):
    a.append(x)
    print("Forward index value", a[2])
    print("Reverse index value", a[-1])
```

Comment: Can you explain more ?  baby steps if its ok

Comment: @Fahad have you tried running the code I showed?

Comment: If only interested on last two items - better use ` lst[-2:]` then.

Comment: Yes i have run it. Its ok i have understood what's happening thank you @roganjosh

Answer (score 1):

If you are baffled by some `python` behiavor it is often useful to add `print` and look what happen, in your code please run following code and try to decude why behavior is different that what you desired

```
def append_sum(lst):
   print(lst,lst[2],lst[1])
   lst.append(lst[2] + lst[1])
   print(lst,lst[2],lst[1])
   lst.append(lst[2] + lst[1])
   print(lst,lst[2],lst[1])
   lst.append(lst[2] + lst[1])
   print(lst)
   return lst
```